# Pytorch installation results in python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, pytorch

I am trying to run:

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir torch
```

but get:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Bla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hcy4wtm0\torch\
```

Google search gives conflicting results and I tried a few of them. Btw, I have a shiny new Anaconda installation.

PS:

So we established that I should use, which I also tried previously:

```
conda install pytorch -c pytorch 
pip3 install torchvision
```

The error I am getting now is:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://pypi.python.org/simple/noarch/repodata.json>
Elapsed: 00:00.119647

The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://pypi.python.org/simple

As of conda 4.3, a valid channel must contain a `noarch/repodata.json` and
associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` file, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is
empty. please request that the channel administrator create
`noarch/repodata.json` and associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state.
Further configuration help can be found at <https://conda.io/docs/config.html>.

A reportable application error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
```

Comment: Are you trying to install torch or pytorch? These are two different things, and the torch Python package belongs to pytorch.

Comment: ultimately I try to get autokeras installed. It complains about the missing torch installation ...

Comment: Okay, so Pytorch.